# Redux Todo List example - how todos state get updated depends on visibility filter

Tags: redux

First of all be patient I'm new at Redux stuff.

I'm reading http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

and all in all I've got the gist but I don't really understand

how the todos state get updated depends on the visibility filter.

I mean, if I click on ie SHOW_COMPLETED,

the SPA shows only the todo with completed: true but why ? and where is the logic ?
I don't see any :(

Usually in a normal script should be sort of

if state.visibiltyFilter === SHOW_COMPLETED filter state ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check under Smart components, at the bottom of containers/App.js you'll see:

```
// This is where the filtering happens
function selectTodos(todos, filter) {
  switch (filter) {
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL:
      return todos
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED:
      return todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ACTIVE:
      return todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
  }
}

// Which props do we want to inject, given the global state?
// Note: use https://github.com/faassen/reselect for better performance.
function select(state) {
  return {
    visibleTodos: selectTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter),
    visibilityFilter: state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

// Wrap the component to inject dispatch and state into it
export default connect(select)(App)
```

The filtering happens when you connect the component to the store. 
Instead of storing a filtered list in the state you just specify that for this particular component you should filter the todos that you get from the store before you pass them to you component as props.